# Create column based on next row column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a column (next_node) which contains the value of the next row node if `status` is success.

```
node | status    | next_node
1    |   success |  2
2    |   fail    | nan
3    |   success |  4
4    |   success |  5
```

What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: `df["node"].shift(-1).where(df["status"].eq("success"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`df.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
In [23]: import numpy as np
In [24]: df['next_node'] = np.where(df.status.eq('success'), df.node.shift(-1), np.nan)

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
   node   status  next_node
0     1  success        2.0
1     2     fail        NaN
2     3  success        4.0
3     4  success        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to put other conditions?